# Example of a homeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0 \}$?

Tags: real-analysis, group-theory

Does a homeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0 \}$ exist?

Comment: How much topology do you know?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?  What do you think the answer should be? What have you tried?

Comment: I thought of $e^{x}$ but it does not cover the negative real numbers...

Comment: One is connected and the other is disconnected

Comment: If $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ is continuous and $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ are such that $\phi(a)=-1$ and $\phi(b)=1$, then ... [fill in details] ... a contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a continuous function from $\mathbb R\smallsetminus\{0\}$ into $\mathbb R$ that has only two values. It follows from the intermediate value theorem that no continuous function from $\mathbb R$ into $\mathbb R$ has only two values.

Suppose $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R\smallsetminus\{0\}$ is a homeomorphism, and $g:\mathbb R\smallsetminus\{0\}\to\{0,1\}$ is given by $$g(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } x<0, \\ 1 & \text{if } x>0. \end{cases}$$
Then $g\circ f: \mathbb R\to\{0,1\}$ is continuous and has both $0$ and $1$ and nothing else in its image. But that is what the intermediate value theorem tells us cannot happen.